# get value from string

Tags: jquery, parsing

I have a string from json data as below:-

"Order Number : 123i the prodfuct is hard to found Title Name superman Product Code :ABC01 Number Of Instances :1 Duration : 10.91 Size : 0.0 Product Cost : $10.43 Product Code :HELLO123 Number Of Instances :1 Duration : 0.91 Size : 0.0 Product Cost : $0.0 "

I want to separate the values into an array!

Need help, i am new to jquery, and tried other option's to!

Comment: Can you obtain the data in a better form?  This is a bit of a mess to parse as there appears to be no reliable rule that determines the boundary between the end of a piece of data and the start of the next key.  Both data and keys can have spaces in them and there are no separators between the end of previous data and start of the next key.  It cannot be parsed reliably as it is unless all the keys are known.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this is not JSON and has nothing to do with JSON.  This is just a string with colons after the keys.

Comment: That's not JSON - Also you should elaborate on how the string should be separated into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to format your *json* string correctly using commas to separate key value pairs, making sure your key names don't have spaces in them and using double quotes to wrap non-numeric values. For ex:

```
{
  Order_Number : "123i the prodfuct is hard to found Title Name superman", 
  Products: [
    { 
      Product_Code : "ABC01",
      Number_Of_Instances : 1,
      Duration: 10.91,
      Size : 0.0,
      Product_Cost : "$10.43"
    },
    { 
      Product_Code : "ABC02",
      Number_Of_Instances : 2,
      Duration: 5.91,
      Size : 0.0,
      Product_Cost : "$5.43"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you have this data in a json string, you can parse it like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var orderNumber = data.Order_Number; // this is your order number

// this is how you iterate through the products in the order
for(product in data.Products) {
  var code = product.Product_Code;
  var instances = product.Number_Of_Instances;
  // and so on..
}
```